# LINUX ADDED SECOND ISSUE? php script works but when I execute using cron job it has double entries in database

Tags: php, linux, curl, cron

This was a perfect working system prior to today. The code has not been updated at all. There is a cron job that runs the php script via curl.

The problem: duplicate entries in the database.

Tried: 
-turning off cron job and manually running curl (several iterations) with success.

-turned cron job back on to run the curl (failed- duplicate entries)

-checked for duplicate cron jobs, there are none.

It makes no sense that it would work independently but then the cron job does this.

Please help. Any ideas would be helpful. I am at a loss.

Comment: we need your source code!

Comment: There were similar issues with cron at the time of the last leap second.... http://blogs.atlassian.com/2015/06/atlassian-application-administrators-need-know-leap-second-bug-lurking-systems/

Comment: It ended up being a leap second issue with the server. I updated the server which the company had not done for a few years and this resolved my issue! Thank you Mark Baker!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rebooted the sever. This was definitely the leap second that was somehow affecting my cron job -> mysql queries

Comment: If you think this might be your issue check the date of the server installation to see if it was prior to 2012